# How can I generate 40gbps traffic?

Tags: networking

I am using Intel X710 ethernet controller (4 x 10G port) and DPDK + DPDK pktgen to generate 40gbps traffic. I can reach 10Gbps with one port and one core, 20Gbps with two ports and two cores but can’t reach 40gbps with four cores and four ports. ( 28gbps is the limit )

I checked PCIe 3.0 slot, memory bandwidth and CPU’s socket location but nothing seems to be matter.

What could be a problem?

using Intel xeon e5 2690 x2, sun microsystem’s mainboard X9DRG-QF, 112GB ram.

The exact command I used is `sudo -E ./app/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/pktgen -l 0,1,2,3,4 -n 8 --proc-type primary -- -N -T -P -m 1.0 -m 2.1 -m 3.2 -m 4.3 -f themes/black-yellow.theme.`

The output of cpu_layout.py is

```
cores =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
sockets =  [0, 1]

       Socket 0        Socket 1       
       --------        --------       
Core 0 [0, 16]         [8, 24]        
Core 1 [1, 17]         [9, 25]        
Core 2 [2, 18]         [10, 26]       
Core 3 [3, 19]         [11, 27]       
Core 4 [4, 20]         [12, 28]       
Core 5 [5, 21]         [13, 29]       
Core 6 [6, 22]         [14, 30]       
Core 7 [7, 23]         [15, 31]
```

DPDK : 17.11.3
pktgen : 3.5.0

Thanks.

Comment: The Intel X710 cards are resoundingly regarded as mangy dogs - you might be hitting the actual max that card is capable of.  https://lonesysadmin.net/2018/02/28/intel-x710-nics-are-crap/

Answer (score 1):

I have X710 with 4 * 10G with E5-2699v4 running at 2.2Ghz. I am able to generate 40Gbps of traffic with a packet size of 128bytes. If I use 64 bytes packets, I am able to generate 30Mpps.

Settings I have used isolcpus and nohz_full on desired cpu, X710 and cores are on same NUMA, and Assigning separate rx|tx threads for the ports '-m [1:2].0, [3:4].1, [5:6].2, [7:8].3'.